# How to get a child attribute from JSONObject Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a problem in my code where I need to print a child attribute from a JSONObject. Actually, I want to have the attribute values in a JSONArray because of some purposes.

**<--So far I did-->**

```
String preStringSingle = responseSingle.body().string(); // has the JSONObject
JSONObject resultsJObject = new JSONObject(preStringSingle);
JSONArray resultsJArray1 = resultsJObject.optJSONArray("data");
System.out.println(resultsJArray1);
```

**<--JSONObject-->**

```
 "status": true,
"locale": "en-US",
"error_code": null,
"message": "OK",
"data": [
    {
        "service_list_access_mode": 0,
        "service_list_domain": "http://www.hotsalesmarket.com",
        "service_list_auth_method": 0,
        "service_list_auth_user": null,
        "service_list_auth_password": null,
        "http_method": "GET",
        "map_service_lists": [
            {
                "path": "sdfm.assets/assets/cameras/5799.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 5799
            },
            {
                "path": "dsf.assets/assets/cameras/5798.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 5798
            },
            {
                "path": "sdfsdf.assets/assets/cameras/6701.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 6701
            }
        ]
    }
],
"timestamp": "2017-06-20T03:46:38Z"
}
```

I wanted to get all the details in the child attribute "map_service_lists".

**<--Desired output-->**

```
{
    "path": "sdfsdf.assets/assets/cameras/5799.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 5799
},
{
    "path": "/sdfsdfs.assets/assets/cameras/5798.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 5798
},
{
    "path": "/sdfsdf.assets/assets/cameras/6701.jpg",
                "service_item_id": 6701
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the whole array?

Comment: Sorry, big mess up there, try this: `JSONArray mapServiceList = resultsJArray1.getJsonObject(0).getJSONArray("map_service_lists");` I'm just guessing from the Javadocs here so let me know how it goes.

Comment: It doesn't work. After the `getJSONObject(0)` there should be an `int` parameter and there is no any `string` parameter passing functions.

Comment: Interesting, maybe I got it wrong somehow, check out the Javadocs here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html and here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to continue like you did, but additional level down the hierarchy:

```
JSONArray data        = resultsJObject.optJSONArray("data");
JSONObject firstData  = data.optJSONObject(0);
JSONArray services    = firstData.optJSONArray("map_service_lists");

System.out.println(services);
```

(Remove the array brackets from the result if you don't want them).

Answer (score 0):

```
String preStringSingle = responseSingle.body().string();
JSONObject resultsJObject = new JSONObject(preStringSingle);
JSONArray resultsJArray1 = resultsJObject.optJSONArray("data");
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(resultsJArray1.get(0).toString());
JSONArray resultsJArray2 = j.optJSONArray("map_service_lists");
System.out.println(resultsJArray2);
```